# How to connect to red bear beacon by alt beacon library

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am trying to read red bear beacon advertisement by alt beacon library. I am able to detect the beacon by:

```
mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0x004C,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

But in advertisement I am getting nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Although it has been a long time since this question was posted,
this might help someone else.

Red Bear's BLE Mini beacon firmware follows Apple's iBeacon definition. The format of advertising should be

00~01 : Manufacturer's company identifier code. (0x4C00)
02~03 : iBeacon advertisement indicator (0x0215)
04~19 : UUID (Default : E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0)
20~21 : Major ID (Default : 0)
22~23 : Minor ID (Default : 0)
24    : Tx Power

You could set format as follows,

```
mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

Ref :

1. Bluetooth Core Spec v4.2 p2081 "Advertising and Scan response
   data format"
2. [AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/spec)
3. [iBeacon introduction](http://www.havlena.net/en/location-technologies/ibeacons-how-do-they-technically-work/)
4. [Lib API](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/index.html?org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html)

Comment: Sorry to reply late. The problem was in that particular device model. it was detecting the the beacon alright but was returning the empty advertisement.